# How to use RegEx in Notepad++ to select spaces up to a specific matching character for replacement

Tags: microsoft-excel, notepad++, regex

Problem: I need to modify hundreds of rows in a .csv for an import, the import software does not like spaces in the name field (but will accept them in the description field) so I need to replace only spaces on each line up to the first "quotation mark".

Example Line:

```
West Side Switch 1,33,"Incl...
```

Would want it to look like:

```
West-Side-Switch-1,33,"Incl...
```

I am not super familiar with working with regex so i figured this would be a good learning opportunity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Notepad++, here is a way to do the job, this will replace all spaces present before the first double quote:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:^|\G)([^"\h]*)\h`
- Replace with: `$1-`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:         : start non capture group
  ^         : beginning of line
 |          : OR
  \G        : search from the last match position
)           : end group
(           : start group 1
  [^"\h]*   : 0 or more character that is not a quote or a horizontal space
)           : end group
\h          : horizontal space
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          : content of group 1
-           : a dash
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you for the detailed explanation.